# Configuration arm-buildroot-linux-gnu not supported

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling, toolchain

I am trying to build latest u-boot for my custom i.MX6 Board.. The latest u-boot requires GCC Version 6.0 and above, if it is less, it will throw an error:

```
Your GCC is older than 6.0 and is not supported
```

I had buildroot version 2017.02.7. I then executed the following steps.

```
make ARCH=ARM menuconfig
```

In the tool chain section i selected ( gcc 6.x ).

While it was configuring the gcc 6.0 , it failed with the following error.

```
*** Configuration arm-buildroot-linux-gnu not supported
make[2]: *** [configure-gcc] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/home/lloyd/buildroot/buildroot-2017.02.7/output/build/host-gcc-initial-6.3.0/.stamp_built] Error 2
make: *** [_all] Error 2
```

How to debug/what can be the issue

Comment: You should probably state when those messages arrive. Just a guess, but...  `configure.ac` has the test, and `configure` is performing the test. Maybe you can try to sidestep the failure by removing the test.

Comment: Is there any way to find out what is causing the actual issue, may be I am missing some dependencies

Answer (score 0):

as [here](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/Your-gcc-is-older-than-6-0-and-is-not-supported/td-p/847387) disscussed, problem is with your toolchain. you can get latest version of required toolcahin from [here](http://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/6.2-2016.11/).